# Django REST API return fields from ForeignKey in related model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

With the following models:

```
class Tabs(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class DataLink(models.Model):
    data_id = models.ForeignKey(...)
    tabs_id = models.ForeignKey(Tabs, ...)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.data_id, self.tabs_id)
```

---

```
DataLink:                               Tabs:
  id  |  data_id  |  tabs_id       |      id  |  name  
------+-----------+-----------     |    ------+--------
  1   |     1     |    1           |      1   |  tab1
  2   |     1     |    2           |      2   |  tab2
  3   |     1     |    3           |      3   |  tab3
  4   |     2     |    1           |      4   |  tab4
  5   |     2     |    4           |      5   |  tab5
```

I need to link data between two models/tables such that for a given `data_id` I can return a list of corresponding tabs, using the `Tabs` table and the `tabs_id`.

For example:

`data_id = 1` would return `['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3']`

`data_id = 2` would return `['tab1', 'tab4']`

Is this possible? How? Is it a bad idea?

Comment: You have already linked the tables in that way. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want a flattened list like that given a data id, you should use values list with the key-value you want and the flat=True kwarg.

it would look something like this. try it in your shell.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

```
DataLink.objects.filter(data_id=1).values_list('tabs_id',flat=True)
```

also, you tagged the question with django **rest** but has no restful context. this appears to be only a Django question.